# How to access the tag of ProtoMember properties in Protobuf-net

Tags: protobuf-net

I am trying to find a way to access the proto members tag and type as a collection. Is there a method in protobuf-net where I can pass in the ProtoContract class and read the tags(order) and type of proto members in the class?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; the `TypeModel` has all this configuration. `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(yourtype, true)` should return an object that represents `yourtype` - the `true` says to apply standard rules (rather than manual configuration). This provides access to the members as well as lots of other configuration information about the type.

Comment: Thanks Marc, While trying to deserialize a class, I can see the Start group WireType for a sub Item. But not the End group. So how Can I understand that, I have reached the end of the sub item?

Comment: @djn you need to `StartSubItem` (IIRC), then loop reading headers until you get something non-positive, which means the sub-item has ended; then `EndSubItem` passing in the token you got from `StartSubItem`